# Customized function to load content using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a function in javascript that receive two arguments (target, content) to load content with ajax using $.load() jquery function, the code is above:

```
 function cargarContenido(content,target) { 
    $(target).load(content);
 }
```

I call the function like that and it doesn't work:

```
<a href="#" onclick="cargarContenido('hd.html','content')">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your target is an invalid selector. You need something like `#content`

```
<a href="#" onclick="cargarContenido('hd.html','#content')">
```

Comment: Thanks! One more thing, in the same code how i can prevent the default behavior when i the link is clicked?

Comment: just add `return false;` as the last call in you method.